# how to turnoff hydration in ipad phonegap android eclipse

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, ipad, cordova

I successfully created an application using android but when i build it using build.phonegap.com for ipad. keyboard is not working in ipad i found an article given below that turn off hydration but nobody told me how to turn off hydration is in ipad setting or in code. im new to mobile applciation
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/grey_screen_when_launching_android_package

Answer (score 1):

After some search i found out https://build.phonegap.com/apps/206892#pane=app-details
there is a checkbox in settings tab besides rebuildall. this might help someone who is new to phonegap. Just sign-up in [build.phonegap.com](http://build.phonegap.com) with [github](https://github.com/) 
and upload you www.zip code and  just uncheck (use hydration) and it worked